# How to get the street name, number, city, state from Google Geocoding API using PHP?

Tags: php, api, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to re-format addresses.

So I want to use Google Geocoding API.
here is an output

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "301",
               "short_name" : "301",
               "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "880",
               "short_name" : "880",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "N Street",
               "short_name" : "N St",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "South Addition",
               "short_name" : "South Addition",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Anchorage",
               "short_name" : "Anchorage",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Anchorage",
               "short_name" : "Anchorage",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Alaska",
               "short_name" : "AK",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "99501",
               "short_name" : "99501",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "880 N Street #301, Anchorage, AK 99501, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 61.21391800000001,
               "lng" : -149.908357
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 61.21526698029151,
                  "lng" : -149.9070080197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 61.2125690197085,
                  "lng" : -149.9097059802915
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How do I get the street number, street address, suite # (if any), city, state, zipcode.

The part that are confusing me is that the address_component has different components. How can I tell what each one stand for?

I thought I can do something like this to get what I need

```
<?php
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$c = $obj['results'][0]['address_components'];
echo '</pre>';
echo 'BUILDING NAME: ' . $c[1]['long_name'] . "<br>\n";
echo 'BUILDING NUMBER: ' . $c[2]['long_name'] . "<br>\n";
echo 'STREET NAME: ' . $c[3]['long_name'] . "<br>\n";
echo 'CITY: ' . $c[5]['long_name'] . "<br>\n";
echo 'COUNTY: ' . $c[6]['long_name'] . "<br>\n";
echo 'STATE: ' . $c[7]['short_name'] . "<br>\n";
echo 'COUNTRY: ' . $c[8]['short_name'] . "<br>\n";
echo 'POSTAL CODE: ' . $c[9]['short_name'] . "<br>\n";
?>
```

But this will not work for all addresses. using the above address here is my output. as you can tell the labels do not match the data.

```
BUILDING NAME: 880
BUILDING NUMBER: N Street
STREET NAME: South Addition
CITY: Anchorage
COUNTY: Alaska
STATE: US
COUNTRY: 99501
```

How can I get the desired results to be correct every time?
My assumption that I would somehow have to check the type value but I am not sure on how and what are the rules that I would need to look at.

Comment: That's what the "types" index is for.

Comment: what is the "types" index detentions? In some cases I seen administrative_area_level_2, administrative_area_level_1, administrative_area_level_3, political, locality  what are all possible values and how to I defined them?

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick function I threw together and here's a [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/WCTQi):

```
function getAddress($elements){ 
    $addr = []; 
    foreach($elements as $e){ 
         if(isset($e['types']) && in_array("street_number",$e['types'])) $addr['street_number'] = $e['long_name']; 
         if(isset($e['types']) && in_array("street_number",$e['types'])) $addr['route'] = $e['long_name']; 
         if(isset($e['types']) && in_array("administrative_area_level_2",$e['types'])) $addr['city'] = $e['long_name']; 
    } 
    return $addr; 
}
```

I didn't do all the work for you though. This is just to give you an example of how to do it. You'll have to edit it to get the rest of the info.

Sample usage:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true); 
$c = $obj['results'][0]['address_components']; 
$address_parts = getAddress($c);
```

Outputs a simple array:

```
array(3) { ["street_number"]=> string(3) "880" ["route"]=> string(3) "880" ["city"]=> string(9) "Anchorage" }
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually appreciate you are not doing the work for me. I figure it out. the only thing that I have left is to understand the difference between administrative_area_level_1, administrative_area_level_2, administrative_area_level_3, administrative_area_level_4, administrative_area_level_5

Comment: If your addresses are in the US, administrative_area_level_1 is the state, ie Florida, locality is the city. Other administrative_area_level_* Level_2 is the county and the rest are irrelevant.